# Using case-when statement in stored procedure Syntax

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, syntax, switch-statement, mariadb

After changing from `IF....ELSE IF...ELSE` to `SWITCH`. I'm getting Error Code: 1064

Instead of `IF....ELSE IF...ELSE` statement executes different codes for more than two conditions, rather preferring to the above I had changed to 
`SWITCH` statement to perform one single actions based on different conditions and later to `break` out of `SWITCH` condition rather executing `IF` conditions several times.

Especially with `CASE  WHEN FeedFlagStatus == '5' THEN`

> Error Code: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '= 5 THEN
>                             UPDATE `feed_item_setting` SET `read_status` = ReadStatus WHERE' at line 23

```
DELIMITER @@;

CREATE 
    PROCEDURE `saveProfileSetting`(IN `UserId` BIGINT, IN `FeedFlagStatus` INT, IN `ReadStatus` INT, IN `WriteStatus` INT, IN `WriteCmtStatus` INT) 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    CONTAINS SQL 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE userid VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE noOfHits INT(11);
        DECLARE noOfHits2 INT(11);
        DECLARE intCode INT(11);

        SET userid = UserId;

        SET noOfHits = ( SELECT `user_id` FROM `feed_item_setting` WHERE `user_id` = UserId );
        SET noOfHits2 = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `feed_item_setting` WHERE `user_id` = UserId );

            IF EXISTS (SELECT `user_id` FROM `feed_item_setting` WHERE `user_id` = UserId ) THEN  
                BEGIN

                    CASE  
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus == 5 THEN
                            UPDATE `feed_item_setting` SET `read_status` = ReadStatus WHERE `user_id` = UserId;
                            SET intCode = FeedFlagStatus;
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus == 6 THEN
                            UPDATE `feed_item_setting` SET `write_status` = WriteStatus WHERE `user_id` = UserId;
                            SET intCode = FeedFlagStatus;
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus == 7 THEN
                            UPDATE `feed_item_setting` SET `write_cmt_status` = WriteCmtStatus WHERE `user_id` = UserId;
                            SET intCode = FeedFlagStatus;
                    END CASE;
                END;            
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    CASE  
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus == 5 THEN
                            INSERT INTO `feed_item_setting` (`user_id`, `read_status`) VALUES (UserId, ReadStatus);
                            SET intCode = FeedFlagStatus;
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus == 6 THEN
                            INSERT INTO `feed_item_setting` (`user_id`, `write_status`) VALUES (UserId, WriteStatus);
                            SET intCode = FeedFlagStatus;
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus == 7 THEN
                            INSERT INTO `feed_item_setting` (`user_id`, `write_cmt_status`) VALUES (UserId, WriteCmtStatus);
                            SET intCode = FeedFlagStatus;
                    END CASE;
                END;
            END IF;



        SELECT userid, noOfHits, noOfHits2, intCode;
    END;

@@;  -- Altered delimiter terminated compound statement

DELIMITER ; -- restore delimiter to standard semicolon
```

Comment: Single `=` instead of double `==`?

Comment: Executed Successfully. I taught it was an assignment operator `=`. It's actually an  equality operator @jarlh

Comment: SQL, and some other languages, has single `=` for both comparison and assignment.

Comment: @jarlh - not always:  `SELECT @var := expression ...` -- the colon is needed to disambiguate.  Meanwhile, `SET @var ...` can use either.

Answer (score 0):

It has used a single equals sign for comparison since the early '70s developed by IBM It was originally named Structured English Query Language, so it's intended to be close to regular human language.

Assignment to a session variable is denoted by `:=` and assigning to variable can be done in the following way

```
DECLARE locRecord VARCHAR(255);
SELECT * INTO locRecord FROM `location_map` WHERE `user_id` = UserId;
```

---

```
DELIMITER @@;

CREATE 
    PROCEDURE `saveProfileSetting`(IN `UserId` BIGINT, IN `FeedFlagStatus` INT, IN `ReadStatus` INT, IN `WriteStatus` INT, IN `WriteCmtStatus` INT) 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    CONTAINS SQL 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE userid VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE noOfHits INT(11);
        DECLARE noOfHits2 INT(11);
        DECLARE intCode INT(11);

        SET userid = UserId;

        SET noOfHits = ( SELECT `user_id` FROM `feed_item_setting` WHERE `user_id` = UserId );
        SET noOfHits2 = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `feed_item_setting` WHERE `user_id` = UserId );
        -- IF ( SELECT count(*) FROM `group_users` WHERE `group_id` = groupId AND `userid` = userId AND `stataus` = 1 ) > 0 THEN


            IF EXISTS (SELECT `user_id` FROM `feed_item_setting` WHERE `user_id` = UserId ) THEN  
                BEGIN

                    CASE  
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus = 5 THEN
                            UPDATE `feed_item_setting` SET `read_status` = ReadStatus WHERE `user_id` = UserId;
                            SET intCode:= FeedFlagStatus;
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus = 6 THEN
                            UPDATE `feed_item_setting` SET `write_status` = WriteStatus WHERE `user_id` = UserId;
                            SET intCode:= FeedFlagStatus;
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus = 7 THEN
                            UPDATE `feed_item_setting` SET `write_cmt_status` = WriteCmtStatus WHERE `user_id` = UserId;
                            SET intCode:= FeedFlagStatus;
                    END CASE;
                END;            
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    CASE  
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus = 5 THEN
                            INSERT INTO `feed_item_setting` (`user_id`, `read_status`) VALUES (UserId, ReadStatus);
                            SET intCode:= FeedFlagStatus;
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus = 6 THEN
                            INSERT INTO `feed_item_setting` (`user_id`, `write_status`) VALUES (UserId, WriteStatus);
                            SET intCode:= FeedFlagStatus;
                        WHEN FeedFlagStatus = 7 THEN
                            INSERT INTO `feed_item_setting` (`user_id`, `write_cmt_status`) VALUES (UserId, WriteCmtStatus);
                            SET intCode:= FeedFlagStatus;
                    END CASE;
                END;
            END IF;



        SELECT userid, noOfHits, noOfHits2, intCode;
    END;

@@;  -- Altered delimiter terminated compound statement

DELIMITER ; -- restore delimiter to standard semicolon
```

*History repeats itself for those Who Do Not Pay Attention and Learn were Doomed To Repeat It again. Isn't it obvious?*